# How to I start a rails console with pry turned off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Sometimes I have reason to want to start the rails console as an irb repl rather than pry (as awesome as pry is). It will default to pry because pry has in the Gemfile. Hows is that done nowadays?

I think there used to be a --irb option when running `rails console` but that seems to be gone now. I get a deprecation error message when I try it.

**More details**

If I just run "rails console" it takes me to pry.

If I run "rails console -irb=irb":

```
$ rails c -irb=irb                                                                                                                                                                         
--irb option is no longer supported. Invoke `/your/choice/of/ruby script/rails console` instead
```

Relevent lines from my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-plus'
```

Comment: pry is awesome in some aspects, yet IRB remains more stable/reliable when doing some operations (especially copy-paste)

Comment: Reverse: If `rails c` opens up `irb` but you want `pry` to open, then do `pry -r ./config/environment`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Launching pry when calling `rails console` or `rails c` is set up by the [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) gem. If you look in the pry-rails issues [there is one](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails/issues/62) that describes a solution.

Define the environment variable `DISABLE_PRY_RAILS` as `1`.

So you can call rails console without pry with:

```
DISABLE_PRY_RAILS=1 rails c
```

Comment: This is very nice.  Note that you'll also need to run `spring stop` first, before calling the above.

Answer (score 6):

Works in Rails 4: In your `application.rb`, inside your Application class, drop this puppy in.

```
# Use the IRB console instead of the Pry one
console do
  require 'irb'
  config.console = IRB
end
```

I couldn't take the Pry console anymore. It kept putting my cursor in odd places at unpredictable times. I can't even describe it but if you know what I'm talking about and know the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answers above, I added the following to the class definition in `application.rb` so that Pry is toggleable from the console:

```
console do
  if ENV['IRB']
    require 'irb'
    config.console = IRB
  end
end
```

You can then run `rails c` to get a Pry console, and `IRB=true rails c` to get an IRB console. This is easily modified if you want the inverse. Works in Rails 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone who runs into the same problem, this is my (crappy) workaround.

I wrapped the pry gems in Gemfile with this:

```
...
unless ENV['NOPRY']
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-plus'
end
...
```

Then run this from the unix terminal:

```
NOPRY=true bundle install
NOPRY=true rails console
```

Not pretty, but gets the job done...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it once console has already been started via `IRB.start` method.